# Python waiting until condition is met

Tags: python

I've created a GUI that ask the user an User/Password. The class that creates the GUI calls another class that creates a web browser and try to login in a website using a method of the same class. If the login is successful, a variable of the GUI's object becomes 'True'

My main file is the next one :

```
from AskUserPassword import AskGUI
from MainInterfaceGUI import MainGUI

Ask = AskGUI()
Ask = Ask.show()

MainInterface = MainGUI()

if Ask.LoginSuccesful == True:
    Ask.close()
    MainInterface.show()
```

If the login is successful, I would like to hide the User/Password GUI and show the main GUI. The code above clearly doesn't work.

How can I make Python to wait until some condition of this type is met ?

Comment: You can trigger the if statement on a "Login Button" click.

Comment: Of course I can, but I prefer to have all the structure in the main file. This is a reduced example but If I start to trigger from a method inside a class that is also inside another class... it's going to be hard to understand

Comment: Without knowing anything about the classes involved, it's not at all clear whether the code you show works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constantly checking for the condition to be met, why not supply what you want upon login to do as a callback to your `AskGUI` object, and then have the `AskGUI` object call the callback when login is attempted? Something like:

```
def on_login(ask_gui):
    if ask_gui.LoginSuccesful:
        ask_gui.close()
        MainInterface.show()


Ask = AskGUI()
Ask.login_callback = on_login
```

Then, in `AskGUI`, when the login button is clicked and you check the credentials, you do:

```
def on_login_click(self):
    ... 
    # Check login credentials.
    self.LoginSuccessful = True

    # Try to get self.login_callback, return None if it doesn't exist.
    callback_function = getattr(self, 'login_callback', None) 
    if callback_function is not None:
        callback_function(self)
```

---

Re.

> I prefer to have all the structure in the main file. This is a reduced example but If I start to trigger from a method inside a class that is also inside another class... it's going to be hard to understand

I recommend this way because all the code to handle something that happens upon login is included in the class that needs to do the logging in. The code to handle which UI elements to display (`on_login()`) is included in the class that handles that.
You don't need anything in the background that keeps checking to see if `Ask.LoginSuccessful` has changed.
When you use a decent IDE, it's pretty easy to keep track of where each function is defined.